# How to count laravel search result?

Tags: laravel

I would like to add this result's total numbers.

Here is my query. It worked fine just display images.

Could you teach me how to write query and blade file please ?

```
   public function allimg()
    {        
        $images = ImageGallery::whereNotNull('image')->where('image', '!=', '')->limit(200.)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('allimg',compact('images'));
        
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `blade.php` this will give you the total number of images.

```php
{{$images->count()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`->count()`

You can chain this method to get the count from a model.

Answer (score 1):

As per Laravel Documentation under queries (See link: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries)

You can use Aggregate Methods such as: count, max, min, avg and sum.

So in your case, you can use count()